# Apigee error when behind gateway proxy

Tags: javascript, apigee

I'm creating an HTML 5 client to app services, however our app services are enterprise so behind an apigee gateway proxy ( not directly through api.usergrid.com).
I'm initializing like this:

```
$(function() {
    var client = new Apigee.Client({
        orgName:'myorg',
        appName:'sandbox',
        monitoringEnabled:false,
        URI:'https://prod.OURURL.com/appservices/v1'
    });
    var username = "myusername";
    var password = "mypass";

    client.login(username, password,
      function (err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('There was an error logging you in.');
        } else {
          //login succeeded
          client.getLoggedInUser(function(err, data, user) {
            if(err) {
              //error - could not get logged in user
              console.log("error on lvl2");
            } else {
              if (client.isLoggedIn()){
                appUser = user;
                console.log('data')
               // showFullFeed();
              }
            }
          });

        }
      }
    );    
});
```

I'm immediately getting:

```
Error: Apigee APM configuration unavailable.
```

and then of course:

```
There was an error logging you in.
```

using the trace tool in the proxy I can see this errorr on the request to /proxy_path/org/app/apm/apigeeMobileConfig

```
{"timestamp":"1398263318219","duration":"0","error":"illegal_argument","exception":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException","error_description":"JSON source MUST not be null"}
```

of course this is all called by the above code.

thank you in advance.

[EDIT FOR MORE INFORMATION]
Just tested with my own private org, so not setting the options.URI param, the second log message is normal as I had not created the app user, however the initialization is NOT working on the enterprise org, so this:

```
var client = new Apigee.Client({
            orgName:'myorg',
            appName:'sandbox',
            monitoringEnabled:false,
            URI:'https://prod.OURURL.com/appservices/v1'
        });
```

is returning the APM error.

Comment: I've actually escalated through a p2 ticket as this seems to be an error in the backend service. will report back with findings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need to enable some of the options in the app services app ( inthe configuration option) for this api call to return something, thus enabling the sdk.